# How to make Correlated UPDATE in this particular case?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-update, union

I am facing a problem.

```
If Object_Id('abc','U') is not null
    Drop table  abc
Go
Create Table abc
(
    Strng varchar(max)

)
GO
Insert abc
Select 'shakuntala'
Union All
Select 'shakuntala-anjna'
Union All
Select 'shakuntala-anjna-sharat'
GO
Create Table def
(
    Strng varchar(max),
    Initcap varchar(max)
)
GO
Insert def
Select 'shakuntala', 'Shakuntala'
Union All
Select 'shakuntala-anjna','Anjna'
Union ALl
Select 'shakuntala-anjna','Shakuntala'
Union All
Select 'shakuntala-anjna-sharat', 'Anjna'
Union ALl
Select 'shakuntala-anjna-sharat', 'Shakuntala'
Union ALl
Select 'shakuntala-anjna-sharat', 'Sharat'
GO
```

`Select * From abc` returns

```
Strng
-------
shakuntala
shakuntala-anjna
shakuntala-anjna-sharat
```

I want to UPDATE table `abc` using table `def` so that after updating, `Select * From abc` returns

```
Strng
-------
Shakuntala
Shakuntala-Anjna
Shakuntala-Anjna-Sharat
```

Comment: You didnt explain your problem properly. Try and expand it. The table abc only has a single column and populated. Why do you want to update? any issues with the data there already?

Comment: @MEdwin: Welcome to the thread. I want to Initcap my data in table **abc** using table **def**. No issue with data, just that I want it properly formatted.

Comment: Not clear to me.  What are the rules?

Comment: @paparazzo: What are the rules? I did understand. Are there any rules required here? I want to UPDATE table "abc" using table "def" without cursor. That's the problem definition.

Comment: Want to  update is not a definition.

Answer (score 0):

If the `def` table had a column with an `ID` I would use a `WHILE`.

This way, you can use a `CURSOR`:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(256), @i VARCHAR(256);

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY 
FOR SELECT Strng, Initcap FROM def;

OPEN c;
FETCH c INTO @s, @i;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    UPDATE abc 
    SET Strng = REPLACE(Strng,@i, @i)
    WHERE Strng = @s;

    FETCH c INTO @s, @i;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;

Select * From abc
```

Comment: Is there a way without **cursor**?

Comment: I tried: `Update abc
Set Strng = REPLACE(abc.Strng,def.Initcap,def.Initcap)
From abc
Join def
 On abc.Strng = def.Strng`. After this `Select * From abc` return` `Shakuntala
shakuntala-Anjna
shakuntala-Anjna-sharat`. That's not what I desired. Data in table **abc** should be update to proper Init Cap format.

Comment: I want to make a Correlated UPDATE without using CURSOR.

Comment: Why is CLR required here. There is problem how SQL is internally performing the UPDATE statement. There are 2 records in table "abc". And second and third record  is being UPDATED multiple times.  SQL is not doing the UPDATE properly. Do you agree?

Comment: The update with a simple join does not work because the update will be applied to the original row every time, that is, the related row in the join. Then the end result of the update will be only the last update.
You need a loop to itinetate through the table with the words to be replaced. Then you replace the first word and update. The second word will update the updated row first. Not the original.

Comment: You have said: "Then the end result of the update will be only the last update.". There are 3 records in table "abc". Record 1, is updated only once. Record 2 is updated twice. Record 3 is updated thrice. In case of records 2 and 3, which is last UPDATE taking place?

Comment: The update will work like the select for column result:
`select *,
  result = REPLACE(abc.Strng,def.Initcap,def.Initcap)
from abc 
 Join def On 
  abc.Strng = def.Strng`

"shakuntala" last update will be "Shakuntala"
"shakuntala-anjna" last update will be "shakuntala-Anjna"
"shakuntala-anjna-sharat" last update will be "shakuntala-Anjna-sharat"

Comment: "shakuntala" last update will be "Shakuntala", Agreed as there is only one update happening to this record.  "shakuntala-anjna" last update will be "shakuntala-Anjna" , why? This is first update, refer to the results returned by `select *, result = REPLACE(abc.Strng,def.Initcap,def.Initcap) from abc Join def On abc.Strng = def.Strng`. SQL takes into account the first UPDATE of the record and leaves all other. It should do a CUMULATIVE UPDATE. Meaning, the second update of the second record  "shakuntala-anjna" should also take place. And result should be "Shakuntala-Anjna"

Comment: Look at the SET of the UPDATE statement on. `SET Strng = REPLACE(abc.Strng,def.Initcap,def.Initcap)`. Take for example the second record 'shakuntala-anjna', after the first update it becomes 'shakuntala-Anjna', then this value is store in Strng of abc, then the second update takes place on the stored 'shakuntala-Anjna', it becomes `Shakuntala-Anjna`. Is SQL not smart enough to do this?

Comment: "Is SQL not smart enough to do this?"

Apparently no. Not my fault!

Comment: If SQL was able to do CUMULATIVE UPDATE this problem would never arise.

Answer (score 0):

************* WARNING ********************
 NEVER USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION
 This should be considered as a mere exercise to demonstrate
 how a recursive update can be achieved.
 With volumes it will perform badly

As for a attempt at doing Capitalization of words it is also 
 quite poor as capitalization has way too many rules depending
 on locale, linguistic rules and customs.

In SQL Server there is no easy way to do it without the use of a CLR function
************* WARNING ********************

```
If Object_Id('tempdb..#abc','U') is not null
    Drop table  #abc
Go
Create Table #abc
(
    Strng varchar(max)

)
GO
Insert #abc
Select 'shakuntala'
Union All
Select 'shakuntala-anjna'
Union All
Select 'shakuntala-anjna-sharat'
GO

If Object_Id('tempdb..#def','U') is not null
    Drop table  #def
Go
Create Table #def
(
    Strng varchar(max),
    Initcap varchar(max)
)
GO
Insert #def
Select 'shakuntala', 'Shakuntala'
Union All
Select 'shakuntala-anjna','Anjna'
Union ALl
Select 'shakuntala-anjna','Shakuntala'
Union All
Select 'shakuntala-anjna-sharat', 'Anjna'
Union ALl
Select 'shakuntala-anjna-sharat', 'Shakuntala'
Union ALl
Select 'shakuntala-anjna-sharat', 'Sharat'
go

select *
from #abc a

while @@RowCount > 0
begin
    update a
    set a.Strng = replace(a.Strng, d.Initcap, d.Initcap)
    from #abc a
    inner join #def d
    on d.Strng = a.Strng
    and a.Strng not like '%' + d.Initcap + '%' collate Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
end

select *
from #abc a
```

The code above gives the desired output